# Dynamically create variable name in python like sas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, automation, sas, data-science

In a use case in **sas** I have a var defined as **df** = 'Jan'

While working with datasets in sas it is written in a SQl case statement like

*case when a> 10 then 100 else 250 end as var_&df*

output is var_Jan

If I want to do similar thing in python in a dataframe then how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/functions.html#globals) with a listcomp to create the variable *dynamically*.

For the sake of the example and to avoid any confusion, I will use `s = "Jan"` (and not `df = "Jan"`).

So, assuming (`df`) is your dataframe, as the example below :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [3, 17], 'var': ['foo', 'bar']})

print(df, type(df))

    a  var
0   3  foo
1  17  bar <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

You can try this :

```
_ = [exec(f"globals()['{b}_{s}'] = 100 if a>10 else 250") for a,b in zip(df["a"], df["var"])]
```

##### # Output :

```
print(foo_Jan)
#250
print(bar_Jan)
#100
```